# Hide a groupbox and also remove the space where it was present in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my winform, I have three group boxes, based on selection of the 
items in a combobox the second group box(at the center) 
is hidden using **groupbox.visible** property.
The problem is when the second goupbox is hidden, there
seems to be an empty space in the area of the hidden group box, 
I want to move the third group box to the place where second 
group box is present. Can I use any other control instead of group box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually set `Location` and `Size` properties of your third groupbox or (I think better) set `Dock` property of both groupboxes to `Top`, so when your second gb becomes not visible, the third should scroll up to occupy free space.

Comment: When setting third group box property to dock, it goes above the first group box and total alignment of the form is messed! I am not able to find the exact location and size value for moving the third group box to top when second group box is invisible!!!

Comment: @banupriya: can't you get `groupBox2.Location` and `groupBox2.Size`?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to set location and size for groupbox manually using Point class. On setting 'Dock' property for groupbox it went on top of the form. Now your solution worked out for me with little changes, while setting groupbox 2 to visible I set location and size property for both groupbox 2 and 3 manually. Then while making groupbox 2 to visible false I set only location for groupbox 3 i.e., groupbox3.Location = groupbox2.Location. But I didnt set 'dock' property for either of the groupboxes. Now everything works well. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have a small number of options, assuming you are using just the default VS controls.

If you place these group boxes in a flow layout panel, when you make it invisible the layout panel will move other controls into it's previously occupied space.

If you dock the group boxes, making one invisible causes the others to occupy the space if the docking dictates.

If you cannot use layout mechanisms or controls, your only option is to modify the location or size of neighbouring controls to fill the space manually.

**I very much advise** trying to use the layout containers, or find a container online that handles the positioning for you.  Position code buried in the form using potentially lots of "magic" numbers is definitely not maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

you should solve it by chaning control that you're `groupboxes` are in. Their position can't be set to constants. The other solution is to change position of third `groupbox` when you change visibility of the second one.

Answer (score 1):

A `FlowLayoutPanel` should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your solution it worked out with groupbox control itself!